# Get Facebook page talking about value from period of time?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'd like to get the talking about field from some pages. I know I can get this from the like page on the graph api. For example graph.facebook.com/facebook will show me facebooks current talking about value.

But does anyone know if I can specify that value from a certain period? For example what was the talking about value 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `/PAGE_ID/insights/page_storytellers` endpoint. See the [insights FQL documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) for the full list of data that can be accessed. You can append `/day`, `/week` or `/days_28` to this to refine the period of data returned.

You'll need a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) or a user access token from a page admin with `manage_pages` permission to access this data.

You can refine this with the `since` and `until` parameters.

So, to see this data by day for the month of July 2012, you can use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/insights/page_storytellers/day?since=2012-07-01&until=2012-07-31&access_token=XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Then you can't get access to its insights.

Comment: I don't really want its insights. IF you goto http://graph.facebook.com/facebook  you will see a talking about count. Thats what I'm looking for, but I'd ideally like to get a snap shot for a specific time period

Comment: If you want to go back in time, that's insights. Otherwise, all you can get is the current talking about count.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'll just have to do it via the page myself. D'oh.